# xsl not getting accessed by xml on tomcat 6

Tags: xml, xslt

In my application, xml is not getting formatted by its corresponding xsl. This is happening with all xml's.
Path of xsl is different from xml and below is how I declared my path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="/abc/xsl/displaynotes/defaultNotes_2015-09-15 19 34 10.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"><SOAP-ENV:Body><return><IndentStyle>bullet</IndentStyle><SectionSubTitle/><SectionTitle/><SubTitle>no</SubTitle><fax/><GuarantorName>Test, Test ......
```

I checked that xsl is present at mentioned path.
When I put both in same folder(desktop), these are working fine, so I think that xsl is not getting accessed by xml. But not sure why?

I am using tomcat6 as my web server.

Thank you.

Comment: Try an href containing no spaces. The href is supposed to be a URI, and valid URIs cannot contain spaces, so this may be the cause of the trouble. Also check whether the problem occurs on all browsers; and check the media type (MIME type) with which the XML file is served.

Comment: only xsl file name contains spaces and it is working fine when placed in same folder. Although I tried removing space but no success. Also confirmed that MIME type is text/xml. My application by default uses IE browser. Problem is not happening in firefox.
Also, I noticed that with IE, I am not able to open xml files, it give option only to save and not open.

Comment: Then sorry, I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After bit research, I found out that IE looks for registry keys for deciding how to process certain mime types. So I went to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\text/xml[and/or application/xml] and copied values from working machine. This resolved my issue.